# UC Feeds - updating products by SKU

Tags: 7, ubercart, feeds

The main idea is updating prices via feeds. If SKUs are unique, we can update products using this parameter.

Unfortunaly module UC Feeds is able to create only new producs. How to modify UC Feeds for updating products ability?

Comment: After checking the code, it appears that UC feeds does not take "update" OP to consideration..or at least as i can remember, I had to write my own module to do that :(

Comment: it's so sad. why'

Answer (score 1):

How about following these steps?

- Save the original import file
- Update the original file
- Delete the last import
- Import again

Comment: How do you "delete last import"?